# Why use only the first column from the distances?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a clustering (Kmeans was applied and clusters were obtained). The radius for each cluster is being calculated between the center and the observations.

I don't understand this here `[:, 0]` I know we're taking all observations from the first column but why not take the second column as well? What does `[:, 0]` represent?

```
X_distances = euclidean_distances(X, [center])[:, 0]
radius = np.max(X_distances)
```

Comment: This question is lack of details. At least put minimal reproducible code example. Can't have a clear idea about what are you going to do

Comment: it's shown that the radius of a cluster is calculated I don't understand 
the piece of code  , where I pointed if you can explain to me, what does it mean? and why is taken only one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you come across things like this, unpack the code a bit and look at what each piece is giving you.

In this case, [the docs for `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html) — which I assume you are using (please include this sort of information in your questions!) — also tell you what you need to know:

> **Returns: distances:** *ndarray of shape (n_samples_X, n_samples_Y)*

So the function `euclidean_distances(X, Y)` returns a 2D array of all the distances between the points in `X` and the points in `Y`. Your `X` is all your data, and your `Y` is just one point: the centroid of the cluster. Because `Y` is only one point, your resulting distance matrix has only one column. Like this:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 3], [2, 5], [0, 4]])
euclidean_distances(X, [[0, 0]])
```

This gives:

```
array([[3.16227766],
       [5.38516481],
       [4.        ]])
```

So the index `[:, 0]` is getting this column. In fact, you could skip the indexing because `np.max()` doesn't care: it's just going to give you the max of the entire array. So you could reduce your code to:

```
radius = euclidean_distances(X, [center]).max()
```

Comment: thanks but in case I skipped the indexing I'd have to reshape the output may be the indexing was an indirect way to do the reshaping